# Replace illegal charactes in a text by underscore in PHP

Tags: php

i need to replace the illegal characters by underscore(_), 
For Example:
if user given text is "imageЙ ййé.png" need to replace this Й йй characters by _ __ So the overall output must be image_ __é.png. And this replacing must not occur for french characters. I have worked check the below code and help me to get the output.

```html
<?php
$allowed_char_array=array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","à","á","â","ã","ä","å","æ","ç","è","é","ê","ë","ì","í","î","ï","ñ","ò","ó","ô","õ","ö","ð","ø","œ","š","Þ","ù","ú","û","ü","ý","ÿ","ž","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"," ","(",")","-","_",".","@","#","$","%","*","¢","ß","¥","£","™","©","®","ª","×","÷","±","+","-","²","³","¼","½","¾","µ","¿","¶","·","¸","º","°","¯","§","…","¤","¦","≠","¬","ˆ","¨","‰");
$word = 'imageЙ ййé.png';
$file_name = url_rewrite(trim($word));
$file_name2 = strtolower($file_name);
$split = str_split($file_name2);

if(is_array($split) && is_array($allowed_char_array)){
 $result=array_diff($split,$allowed_char_array);
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($split);
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($allowed_char_array);
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($result);
}
function url_rewrite($chaine) {

    // On va formater la chaine de caractère
    // On remplace pour ne plus avoir d'accents
    $accents = array('é','à','è','À','É','È');
    $sans =    array('é','à','è','À','É','È');
    $chaine = str_replace($accents, $sans, $chaine);

    
    return $chaine;
}
?>
```

Comment: you are going to want to look up `mb_` functions for this task.  (e.g. `mb_strtolower()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would build a regex (character class, to be exact) using your whitelisted characters, and then remove any character which matches the negation of that class.

```
$allowed_char_array = array("a","b","c","d","e") // and others
$chars = implode("", $allowed_char_array);
$regex = "/[^" . $chars . "]/u";
$input = "imageЙ ййé.png";
echo $regex . "\n";
$output = preg_replace($regex, "_", $input);
echo $input . "\n" . $output;

imageЙ ййé.png
image_ __é.png
```

If the above be not clear, here is what the actual all to `preg_replace` would look like:

```
preg_replace("/[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv]/u, "_", $input);
```

That is, any non whitelisted character would be replaced with just underscore.  I did not bother to list out the entire character class, because you already have that in your source code.

Note that the `/u` flag in the regex is critical here, because your input string is a UTF-8 string.  UTF-8 characters may consist of more than one byte, and using `preg_replace` on them without `/u` may have unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use `mb_strtolower()` to convert multibyte characters to lowercase safely.

My solution uses `strtr()` to convert your French accented letters to your preferred form.

Since all characters are lowercased from the onset, you can halve your white list of French characters.

Using `pathinfo()` helps you to dissect your filename.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5YKIv))

```
$word = 'imageЙ ййé.png';
$parts = pathinfo($word);
$filename = strtr(mb_strtolower($parts['filename']), ['é' =>'é', 'à' => 'à','è' => 'è']);
echo preg_replace('~[^ a-zéàè]~u', '_', $filename) , "." , $parts['extension'];
```

Output:

```
image_ __é.png
```